# Can I free memory originally allocated from another pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

If I allocated memory from another pointer, then declare a pointer equal to the other pointer, can I then free the memory allocated with the first pointer by using `free()` on the new pointer?

Example:

```
typedef struct foo{
  int n;
  char c;
} foo;

foo* bar = malloc(sizeof(foo));
foo* tmp = bar; // declaring pointer identical to other pointer

free(tmp); // can I do this to free *bar?
```

Comment: Yes. (Character limitation bypass.)

Comment: What if I pass a pointer into a function, can I then free that pointer's memory within the function?

Comment: As long as the pointer points to the same address in memory, you can free the memory at that address. It doesn't matter what the name of the pointer variable is, it matters where it points to.

Comment: Yes, it is standard pratice when, say, traversing a linked list and freeing each node. `free()` has absolutely no idea which of your variables is passing the value to be freed. The important things, are it was a pointer value previously allocated, which has not previously been freed, or `NULL`.

Comment: In addition to comment of @WeatherVane have a look at the Dangling Pointer problem which may be really confusing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer. You will have two pointers, both points invalid object locations to use after `free()`.

Comment: Read about [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is completely fine.

Your implementation of `malloc` will most likely mark the chunk of memory as allocated before returning a pointer to it.

Now you can have as many pointer variables as you want which point to this chunk of memory and you can free that memory by calling `free` on any of them.

The pointer itself doesn't contain information about whether the memory it points to has been allocated. It just points to it.

```
int* i = malloc(sizeof(int) * 23);
int* j = i;

free(j); 
// free(i); // this is undefined behavior, the memory was already freed
```

Comment: Indeed. In fact, almost any use of  `i` is undefined beyond that point, because the variable `i` now contains an indeterminate value, as per *6.2.4p2* of the spec.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do what you are asking about. But it is not another pointer, what you are freeing is the same pointer. When `malloc` returns a pointer, it is essentially giving you an integer that is the address of the start of the chunk of memory that it has reserved for you. When you are done are done with the memory, you pass that address to `free`. As far as `free` is concerned, there is no difference between:

```
free(malloc(17));
```

,

```
void *p = malloc(17);
free(p);
```

or

```
void *p1 = malloc(17);
void *p2 = p1;  
free(p2);
```

In all of these cases the value returned from `malloc` is getting to `free`, and that is all that matters.